# Query to pulled data using Microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I never use Microsoft graph. I just want to query to just pull a selection of users by supervisor using Microsoft graph

Comment: Use Microsoft Graph explorer portal to try out the sample API's, It will help you onboard the Graph API's and also what you are looking for.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Answer (score 1):

Run `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/directReports`

See [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

Create SPFx to call graph api to get users.

[the demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial) had shared how to search/filter users, to get all users, just remove the filter logic.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,mail,userPrincipalName
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you want to get specific user with given email ID. Just change your email ID. The email ID I have given is just an example.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xyz@mail.com?$select=displayName